# $\int (x^2+1)/(x^4+1)\ dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, polynomials, integration-by-parts

I have Divided the numerator and Denominator by $x^2$
to get $\dfrac{1+x^{-2}}{x^2+x^{-2}}$ then changed it into $(1+(x^{-2}))/[(x-x^{-1})^2 +2]$ then took $x-(1/x)$ as $u$ and Differentiated it with respect to $x$ to get $dx=du/(1+x^{-2})$  Finally I got this expression:

$$
\int\frac{x^2+1}{x^4+1} \, dx = \int (u^2+2)^{-1} \, du
$$

After this I need help!

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: Just apply partial fraction decomposition by noticing that $$x^4+1 = (x^2+1)^2-(x\sqrt{2})^2 = (x^2+x\sqrt{2}+1)(x^2-x\sqrt{2}+1)$$

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "then changed it into... But it should be $$x^2+x^{-2}=(x-x^{-1})^2+2$$You forgot the square.

Comment: So after setting $u=x-x^{-1}$, you get $\int \frac{du}{u^2+2}.$ Setting $v=u/\sqrt2$ gets you $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\int \frac{dv}{1+v^2}=\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\arctan(v)+C.$

Comment: Are you missing a square? Thus: $$ \frac{1+x^{-2}}{x^2+x^{-2}} = \frac {1+x^{-2}} {(x-x^{-1})^2 +2} $$ That seems to be clearly what you intended so I've edited the question accordingly.

Comment: Did it! Didn't notice thst.

Comment: Amazing how much commentary is here without anyone mentioning that $\displaystyle \int (1+u^2)^{-1} \,du = \arctan u + \text{constant}. \qquad$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Express MichaelRozenberg's denominator, $x^2 + \sqrt{2} x + 1$ in the form $u^2 + 1$ so you can use the $\tan^{-1}$ form.

Specifically:

$x^2 + \sqrt{2} x + 1$

Let $\sqrt{2}x + 1 = u$,

so

$u^2 = 2 x^2 + 2 \sqrt{2} x + 1$

so

$u^2 + 1 = 2 x^2 + 2 \sqrt{2} x + 2$

or

${1 \over u^2 + 1} = {1 \over x^2 + \sqrt{2} x + 1}$.

And likewise for the other term with the minus sign.

Now you have the arc tan integral formula, giving:

$$\frac{\tan ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{2} x+1\right)-\tan ^{-1}\left(1-\sqrt{2} x\right)}{\sqrt{2}}$$

Comment: Can u please tell me what to do After my last step? I m stuck

Answer (score 7):

Standard tables of integrals say:
$$ \int (1+v^2)^{-1} \, dv = (\arctan v) + \text{constant}. $$

Therefore
\begin{align}
\int (2+u^2)^{-1} \, du & = \frac 1 {2\sqrt 2} \int \left(1 + \left(\frac u {\sqrt 2} \right)^2 \right)^{-1} \, \big( \sqrt 2\, du\big) \\[10pt]
& = \frac 1 {2\sqrt 2} \int (1+v^2)^{-1} \, dv \\[10pt]
& = \frac 1 {2\sqrt 2} \arctan v + C \\[15pt]
& = \frac 1 {2\sqrt 2} \arctan \frac u {\sqrt 2} + C. 
\end{align}

Comment: I think it should be $\int(2+u^2)^{-1}du$, but it's beautiful!

Comment: Thanks Again Sir! I had this part done by the way then too.

Answer (score 6):

Since $x^4+1=x^4+2x^2+1-2x^2=(x^2+\sqrt2x+1)(x^2-\sqrt2x+1)$, we obtain
$$\frac{x^2+1}{x^4+1}=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{x^2+\sqrt2x+1}+\frac{1}{x^2-\sqrt2x+1}\right).$$
Now, use $\int\frac{1}{1+x^2}dx=\arctan{x}+C$.

Comment: Thanks Sir! Helped a lot

Comment: @user126358 You are welcome!

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg : This fails to mention that what the original poster did was correct and actually gets you the answer more simply by going on from where the O.P. left off. (See what my posted answer.)

Comment: @MichaelHardy Thanks Sir!